# \textbf inside a lemma

Tags: math-mode, formatting, theorems, bold

I have defined `lemma` and use it as follows:

```
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
...
\begin{lemma}
abc_\textbf{indice}
\end{lemma}
```

It turns out that the `indice` becomes italic, does anyone know how to just make it bold, not italic?

Comment: You can use the underscore in such contents only in math mode.

Comment: By default LaTeX typesets the contents of a theorem created via `\newtheorem` using `\itshape`, or *italics*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It won't look pretty, but you may switch off italics inside the Lemma by using `\textup{\textbf{indice}}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
\(abc_\textup{\textbf{indice}}\)
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: As egreg has commented, `\mathbf` may be a better choice.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
\(abc_\mathbf{indice}\)
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would be better `\mathbf`, perhaps. Commands such as `\textbf` work correctly in subscripts only if `amsmath` is loaded, though.